# Can't use sqlx Executor as a trait object

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-sqlx, rust-async-std

I need to use the `Executor` type as a trait object but I get the following error:

```rust
the trait `Executor` cannot be made into an object.
the trait cannot be made into an object because it requires `Self: Sized`
```

If we look into the trait definition, we can see how it actually implements `Sized`:

```rust
pub trait Executor<'c>: Send + Debug + Sized {
    type Database: Database;
...
}
```

I basically want to do something like the following:

```rust
struct CustomExecutor<'c> {
    inner: Arc<dyn Executor<'c, Database = Postgres>>,
}
```

I would expect this to work completely fine, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's called [object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety). If a trait has `Sized` as a super trait, it cannot be turned into trait object. Which kind of makes sense intuitively. Trait objects are dynamically sized sort of by definition so they cannot implement a `Sized` trait. But implementing that trait is all they're supposed to do. Not sure how to work around this. Although in your example, you could just use generics, but I assume your real use case is less straight-forward.